# How to pass plot options in the PlotPoints command?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

How can I pass plot options when I use the `PlotPoints` command? I thought that I could find an answer online but I was unable to do so.

The task at hand is to plot the function with thin green and the points with thick black. I naively used the following code

```
stpfnctn[r_] := Piecewise[{{5 - Abs[2]*r, r > 0}, {5 + Abs[2]*r, r < 0}}]

Plot[stpfnctn[r], {r, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, {-1.1, 5}}, 
  Exclusions -> {r == 0}, 
  Mesh -> All, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  PlotPoints -> {25, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Green}, 
  BaseStyle -> {13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
  Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04]]
```

which does not work. The whole plot is preented in thin green colour. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also change the `Mesh` settings to  control the mesh color.

```
positiveColor = 
  Thread[{Subdivide[0, 4, 10], Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}];
negativeColor = 
  Thread[{Subdivide[-4, 0, 20], Directive[Blue, PointSize[Medium]]}];
meshcolor = Catenate[{positiveColor, negativeColor}];

stpfnctn[r_] := 
 Piecewise[{{5 - Abs[2]*r, r > 0}, {5 + Abs[2]*r, r < 0}}]
Plot[stpfnctn[r], {r, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, {-1.1, 5}}, 
 Exclusions -> {r == 0}, Mesh -> {meshcolor}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 PlotPoints -> {25, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Green}, 
 BaseStyle -> {13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's very cool. Much closer to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `stpfnctn[r_] := 
 Piecewise[{{5 - Abs[2]*r, r > 0}, {5 + Abs[2]*r, r < 0}}]
Plot[stpfnctn[r], {r, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, {-1.1, 5}}, 
 Exclusions -> {r == 0}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #1 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, 3, 10], Subdivide[-3, 0, 10]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red], Blue}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> {25, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Green}, 
 BaseStyle -> {13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04]]`

Answer (score 6):

Use `MeshStyle`

```
Plot[stpfnctn[r], {r, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, {-1.1, 5}},
 Exclusions -> {r == 0},
 MaxRecursion -> 0,
 PlotPoints -> 25,
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> Black,
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Green},
 BaseStyle -> {13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"},
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04]]
```

[image]